# Passing Odata object to create an entity set

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to call a Odata service (crequestSet) which will create an article in MDG system.

I need to pass few parameters from the ui5 input fields and some should be hard coded values.

I have created a request.json file under models folder:

{

```
"CR_MARA": {
    "Matk": "",
    "Mtart": "HAWA",
    "Attyp": "01",
    "Meins": "EA"
},
"CR_MAW1": {
    "Wladg": "0001",
    "Wbkla": "3100" 
},
"CR_MARM": {
    "Meinh": "EA",
    "Umrez": "1",
    "Umren": "1"
},
"CR_MAKT": {
    "Spras": "EN",
    "Maktg": "Art 101 A",
    "Maktx": "Art 101 A"

},
"CR_STEU": {
    "Aland": "DE",
    "Tatyp": "TTX1",
    "Taxkm": "0"
}
```

}

Now i am trying to call the service /createrequest by using the model.
Create ('EnitityEset',oData {Success:"",Failure:""}) of the odata model in sapui5.

For a simple JSON model like:

```
{
    "store": "",
    "merchCat": "",
}
```

i can simple do:

```
var oData = {
Store: oLocal.getProperty("/store"),
MerchCat: oLocal.getProperty("/merchCat")

}
```

and then call the create method:

```
oModel.create("/crequestSet", oData, {
                success: this._fnSuccess.bind(this),
                error: this._fnFailed.bind(this)
            })
```

But how do i pass the complex json object:

```
{

    "CR_MARA": {
        "Matk": "",
        "Mtart": "HAWA",
        "Attyp": "01",
        "Meins": "EA"
    },
    "CR_MAW1": {
        "Wladg": "0001",
        "Wbkla": "3100" 
    },}
```

to the oModel.Create ?

I tried to do `var oData = JSONModel.Stringyfy()` to convert into a string,but it's not working and giving a error while service call.

The metadata structure of the crequest service:

```
-<EntityType sap:content-version="1" Name="crequest">


-<Key>

<PropertyRef Name="Matnr"/>

</Key>

<Property Name="ReasonForRequest" sap:filterable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:unicode="false" MaxLength="60" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String"/>

<Property Name="Matnr" sap:filterable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:unicode="false" MaxLength="40" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String" sap:label="Material"/>

<Property Name="CrDescription" sap:filterable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:unicode="false" MaxLength="60" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String"/>

<Property Name="CrequestType" sap:filterable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:unicode="false" MaxLength="8" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String"/>

<Property Name="CrequestId" sap:sortable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:unicode="false" MaxLength="12" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String"/>

<Property Name="Matkl" sap:sortable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:unicode="false" MaxLength="9" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String"/>

<Property Name="RefMatnr" sap:filterable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:unicode="false" MaxLength="40" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String" sap:label="Material"/>

<Property Name="Reason" sap:filterable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:unicode="false" MaxLength="2" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String"/>

<Property Name="Message" sap:filterable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:unicode="false" MaxLength="220" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String" sap:label="Message Text"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_ATTACHMASTER" ToRole="ToRole_CR_ATTACHMASTER" FromRole="FromRole_CR_ATTACHMASTER" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.CR_ATTACHMASTER"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_UOM" ToRole="ToRole_CR_UOM" FromRole="FromRole_CR_UOM" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.CR_UOM"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_MARA" ToRole="ToRole_CR_MARA" FromRole="FromRole_CR_MARA" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.CR_MARA"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_MARC" ToRole="ToRole_CR_MARC" FromRole="FromRole_CR_MARC" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.CR_MARC"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_MAKT" ToRole="ToRole_CR_MAKT" FromRole="FromRole_CR_MAKT" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.CR_MAKT"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_MARD" ToRole="ToRole_CR_MARD" FromRole="FromRole_CR_MARD" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.CR_MARD"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_MARM" ToRole="ToRole_CR_MARM" FromRole="FromRole_CR_MARM" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.CR_MARM"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_MVKE" ToRole="ToRole_CR_MVKE" FromRole="FromRole_CR_MVKE" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.CR_MVKE"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_MAW1" ToRole="ToRole_CR_MAW1" FromRole="FromRole_CR_MAW1" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.CR_MAW1"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_STEU" ToRole="ToRole_CR_STEU" FromRole="FromRole_CR_STEU" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.CR_STEU"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_SAUSPW" ToRole="ToRole_CR_SAUSPW" FromRole="FromRole_CR_SAUSPW" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.CR_SAUSPW"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_SVARKY" ToRole="ToRole_CR_SVARKY" FromRole="FromRole_CR_SVARKY" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.CR_SVARKY"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_PURCHINFO" ToRole="ToRole_CR_PURCHINFO" FromRole="FromRole_CR_PURCHINFO" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.CR_PURCHINFO"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_WLK2" ToRole="ToRole_CR_WLK2" FromRole="FromRole_CR_WLK2" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.CR_WLK2"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_BOM" ToRole="ToRole_CR_BOM" FromRole="FromRole_CR_BOM" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.CR_BOM"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_MBEW" ToRole="ToRole_CR_MBEW" FromRole="FromRole_CR_MBEW" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.CR_MBEW"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_CHARACP" ToRole="ToRole_CR_CHARACP" FromRole="FromRole_CR_CHARACP" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.CR_CHARACP"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_MAMT" ToRole="ToRole_CR_MAMT" FromRole="FromRole_CR_MAMT" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.CR_MAMT"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_CLASSGEN" ToRole="ToRole_cr_classgen" FromRole="FromRole_cr_classgen" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.cr_classgen"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_MESSAGE" ToRole="ToRole_Messages" FromRole="FromRole_Messages" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.Messages"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_CLASSASGN" ToRole="ToRole_Classasgen_As" FromRole="FromRole_Classasgen_As" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.Classasgen_As"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_VALUATION" ToRole="ToRole_Valuation_As" FromRole="FromRole_Valuation_As" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.Valuation_As"/>

<NavigationProperty Name="CR_SEASON" ToRole="ToRole_Season_det" FromRole="FromRole_Season_det" Relationship="UGIOD02_RFM_SRV.Season_det"/>

</EntityType>
```

Comment: It really depends on the structure of your entities in your oData Model. Please share your $metadata as well.

Comment: Hi,i have attached the metadata of the crquest service that i need to call along with passing the values to the create method in the same format.

Comment: Please add the entire metadata and not only one entity

Answer (score 0):

[sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel, method created](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/create) accepts three parameters, being the second (`oData`in the API Reference) the deep object you need to pass.

```
var oData = {
   ReasonForRequest: "X",
   Matnr: "Y",
   RefMatnr: "Z",
   CR_MARA: {
    Matk: "",
    Mtart: "HAWA",
    Attyp: "01",
    Meins: "EA"
   },
  CR_MAW1: [
    {
    Wladg: "0001",
    Wbkla: "3100" 
    }
   ]

}
oModel.create("/EntitySet", oData, { } );
```

Please note some important concepts:

- CR_MARA and CR_MAW1 are your `NavigationProperties` in the metadata.
- As you did only provice your service metadata partially, it's not
  possible to know what are the properties for each entity. The
  `associations` in your metadata (not available in the metadata)
  contain information about cardinalitty.

  - So if `CR_MARA` has
    cardinalitty `1..1` it should be a deep object inside `oData` whilst
    `CR_MAW1` has cardinalitty `1..*` it should be a array of objects
    inside `oData`.

Moreover, it's semantically wrong to name `EntitySets` with "operation specific" names, like "CreateEntitySet" or "DeleteEntitySet" as you can (and tipically will) implement many operations in the same entity like Query, Read and Create at the same time.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for all your help,I was able to resolve the issue with nested json structure and could trigger the article creation service.

Answer (score -1):

The oData model (I assume you use v2) takes care of the structure when you use `oModel.createEntry()` or `oModel.create()`. You can just put the whole object into the second properties argument. I forked a northwind example project [northwind-sapui5](https://github.com/dominikfeininger/northwind-sapui5) to create a working example.

Comment: CreateEntry does not allow deep structures and as a consequence it cannot be used given the JSON structure.